# Supervisord does not start killed processes

Tags: supervisord

I have `supervisord` installed on my Ubuntu 10.04 and it runs a Java process continuously and supposed to heal (reload) process when it somehow dies or crashes.

On my `htop` I send SIGKILL, SIGTERM, SIGHUP, SIGSEGV signals to that **Java process** and watch `/etc/logs/supervisord.log` file and it says.

```
08:09:46,182 INFO success: myprogram entered RUNNING state,[...]
08:38:10,043 INFO exited: myprogram (exit status 0; expected)
```

At `08:38` I kill the process with SIGSEGV. How come it is exited with code 0 and why does not `supervisord` restart it at all?

All my `supervisord.conf` about this specific program is as follows:

```
[program:play-9000]
command=play run /var/www/myprogram/ --%%prod
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/myprogram-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/myprogram-stdout.log
```

Process works really fine when I launch supervisord, however does not get healed.

By the way any ideas how to start supervisord as a service so that it automatically launches when the whole system reboots?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try setting `autorestart=true`.  By default, autorestart is set to "unexpected" which means it will only restart a process if it exits with an unexpected exit code.  By default, exit code 0 is expected.

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings

You can use the chkconfig program to make sure that supervisor starts on reboot.

```
$ sudo apt-get install chkconfig
$ chkconfig -l supervisor
supervisor                0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
```

You can see that it's enabled for runlevels 2-5 by default when I installed it.

```
$ man 7 runlevel
```

for more info on run levels.

Comment: Quite awesome! I was looking for this `autorestart` setting. I was expecting it to be `true` by default and then I got lost in the documentation. BTW I think `chkconfig` requires a process to be a service, however `supervisord` is not a service, therefore that `chkconfig -l` command does not work on me and says `supervisor: unrecognized service`. What do you think for that?

Comment: How did you install supervisor?  If you use apt-get, then it gets installed as a service, at least for Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: It was on 10.04 and I think I installed it using `easy_install`. thanks for noticing that.

Comment: I have done this and does not work autostart=true
autorestart=true, both to true